# атрибут hreflang и canonical

Tags: php, html, seo, веб-сайт

У меня есть 2 идентичные страницы на разных языках index.php и en.php. Как правильно прописать hreflang и canonical в едином header для этих страниц?

Это правильно?

```
if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/index.php" || $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/en.php") {?>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/en" hreflang="en" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/" hreflang="ru" />
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/" hreflang="x-default" />
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://site.ru/"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на странице index.php:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/" hreflang="ru" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/en" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.ru/"/>
```

на странице en.php:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/en" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://site.ru/" hreflang="ru" />
<link rel="canonical" href="https://site.ru/en"/>
```